# Place Details API intermittently not returning all fields

Tags: google-places-api

I am currently making a REST call to the place details api for the rating and review fields. A smaller percentage of requests are coming back with only the rating returned and not the review field. In those cases still getting a 200.

Reviewed examples of these businesses in google and verified they do have reviews. Most recent example had 22. Verified it was the same place id.

My only other thought was maybe a quota issue, however I dont believe I am reaching 100 per second and would generally receive a different status back.

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Here is an example of the call being made: 
{
 "headers": {},
 "follow_redirect": false,
 "auth": {},
 "queries": {
  "language": "en",
  "fields": "rating,review",
  "placeid": "{placeId}",
  "key": "{apiKey}"
 },
 "url": "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json",
 "reject_unauthorized": true
}

Comment: What's the place ID? please post the full request you're making so that we can reproduce this issue from our side.